# Best way to get values corresponding to key codes

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am implementing custom soft keyboard for my app. I define keyboard using XML file and for each key code and label are defined as follows:

```
<Key android:codes="1" android:keyLabel="bla" />
```

I also have a class `A` that implements `OnKeyboardActionListener`. `A` implements method

```
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        // Here I want to retrieve value that corresponds to key with primaryCode

    }
```

What would be the best way to get value corresponding to key code? Do you think defining hashmap with (key code, key value) pairs inside class `A` is a good idea?

The set of keys I will have is limited, ~40.